# External Content Type SQL Authentication

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

Having an issue with the way that SharePoint External Content Types are authenticating to a SQL server table. Currently we have to enable NT Authority\Anonymous Login in the SQL database to allow the content to be loaded. Due to having Foundation, I can not set up a Secure Store. Is there another way to allow a particular SharePoint Group to have access to reading and writing to a connected database? We want this to be as secure as possible.

Environment:
2 SharePoint Foundation 2010 SP2 w/ February CU Servers
1 External Database Server running SQL 2008R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to [configure your environment to use Kerberos](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=196600) on both the SharePoint and SQL servers. Once you have done that you will then use the passthrough option when configuring your External Content Type. Instead of a SharePoint group you will then need to use an AD group.

> **Understanding Passthrough Authentication**
>  Passthrough authentication is in the Impersonation and Delegation authentication
>   model. Setting the value of the AuthenticationMode element to
>   Passthrough causes BCS to use the credentials of the current user to
>   access the external system. Passthrough is simple to set up by
>   selecting Connect with User’s Identity when configuring the external
>   system connection in SharePoint Designer, as was shown in the
>   walk-through earlier in this chapter. However, Passthrough
>   authentication is unlikely to be useful in many situations because of
>   limitations inherent in Windows authentication.
>
> -[*Business Connectivity Services security overview (SharePoint Server 2010)*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661743.aspx)

Configuring Kerberos is a pretty complex process so I can only offer you some links as well as point you in the direction of some tools to help assist you.

- [Identity delegation for Business Connectivity Services (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502600%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- Download and install [the Server 2003 Resource Kit tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) and grab KerbTray
- [The Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046)
- [Configuring Kerberos Authentication for Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products and Technologies](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=196600)  (white paper in MS word format)

You may also find this SQL query helpful to determine which accounts are legged in via NTLM and which via Kerberos.

```
SELECT
    c.session_id
   ,s.login_name
   ,c.auth_scheme
   ,c.net_transport
   ,s.host_name
   ,s.login_time

FROM sys.dm_exec_connections c
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s on s.session_id = c.session_id
```