# How to make Wcf accessable with multiple domains

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, wcf

Below is my WCF service which i have created. I was able to access this service with in the domain.However i want to make this service available across domain through BCS from sharepoint designer. Can you please help me what to make changes in Web.config file and the code so that it is accessible across domain.My Web.config is below.

```
public Vendor[] GetVendors(string strFilter)
        {
            string siteName = "http://myappserver.com/myname/";
            string webName = "Susite2";
            string listName = "Vendors List";
            string fieldTitle = "Title";
            List<Vendor> listVendor = new List<Vendor>();

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteName))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.AllWebs[webName])
                //using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                   SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" + "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>";
                        query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilter))
                            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + strFilter + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
                        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                        if (items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                            {
                                string title = Convert.ToString(item[fieldTitle]);
                                Vendor vendor = new Vendor();
                                vendor.Name = title;
                                vendor.VendorId = item.ID;
                                listVendor.Add(vendor);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                 return listVendor.OrderBy(a => a.Name).Select(a => a).ToArray();
    }
```

WEB.COnfig

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
         <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
    -->
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>

    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
                type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <!-- 
      The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
      Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule" />
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
      <remove name="ScriptResource" />
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
           type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
           type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.05727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SPListData.CustomDataListBehavior"
        name="SPListData.CustomDataList">
        <endpoint address="http://18.15.158.125:186/CustomDataList.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="SPListData.ICustomDataList">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SPListData.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="SPListData.CustomDataListBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

ERROR SCREEN SHOT

[image]

Comment: How is the authentication on your ECT set up? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502600%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: BCS exists to surface data from other domains. It is acting as a proxy client and authenticates directly to the service it connects to. It can either use an account in the Secure Store to authenticate to the service or it can use pass-through which (generally) requires Kerberos. This is not a cross-domain issue. You need to configure the ECT to properly authenticate or the permissions on the list. Post a screen shot of your error.

Comment: Added the screen shot in my orginal issue

Comment: What's the authentication model BCS is using? Impersonate or Pass through?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get you.but if uou see my web.config  Authentication mode is Windows

Comment: I don't believe you understand my question. When you configure your external content type you choose an authentication model. This has nothing to do with the web config. It's in the ECT configuration. Your web.config stores info on how users authenticate to IIS, not how the BCS runtime authenticates to your WCF service.  If you chose passthrough so that SharePoint will pass the current user's Windows credentials you need Kerberos on both the SharePoint server and the WCF server.

Comment: Thanks RObert i am using PASSthrough(User’s Identity). So you mean to say i have to use (impersonated Custom/Windows Identity) or either (BDC Identity) for this??.. if you have tired any of this or any links is Highly appreciated

Comment: I've updated my answer with information regarding how to config passthrough with Kerberos.

Answer (score 1):

When using passthrough as the authentication scheme, you need to configure Kerberos Delegated Authentication for most real world scenarios.

When BCS attempts to use NTLM Windows authentication there is no mechanism for BCS to pass the current user's credentials on to the WCF service. This is why you get the authentication error, because your WCF service is rejecting `AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON`.

When you use Kerberos, BCS is delegated the ability to pass **your** Kerberos ticket on to the WCF service. For Kerberos to work, all servers must be configured with the correct SPNs.

[Here is a link to another question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/91775/4170) where I provide an answer to this same sort of scenario with BCS. Configuring Kerberos is not a trivial task. Here is the most important conceptual detail, though.

> **Understanding Passthrough Authentication**
>  Passthrough authentication is in the Impersonation and Delegation authentication
>   model. Setting the value of the AuthenticationMode element to
>   Passthrough causes BCS to use the credentials of the current user to
>   access the external system. Passthrough is simple to set up by
>   selecting Connect with User’s Identity when configuring the external
>   system connection in SharePoint Designer, as was shown in the
>   walk-through earlier in this chapter. However, Passthrough
>   authentication is unlikely to be useful in many situations because of
>   limitations inherent in Windows authentication.
>
> -[*Business Connectivity Services security overview (SharePoint Server 2010)*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661743.aspx)

As I stated, to get by the limitations of NTLM, you need to configure Kerberos.

Your other option would be to create a service account in Active Directory, add it to the Secure Store and configure BCS to impersonate that account. You would then use SharePoint's authorization mechanism to control who has access to the External List.

**Regarding `basicHttpBinding`**

> By default, the basicHttpBinding security mode is None. ***This
>   default setting means that you do not have authentication and that
>   neither transport nor message security is enabled.*** By enabling
>   Windows authentication with TransportCredentialOnly, you will get
>   authentication, but no message protection; this is similar to how an
>   ASMX Web service works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx

Comment: Hi Robert, I am using sharepoint 2010. I was able to fetch the web service methods in BCS using sharepoint designer. Howeever when i create an external list. i was not able to see the data in this list. It gives me an error Access Debied. I have given permissions to the user in central admin for the External content type but still it gives me an access denied. I suspect this could be because i am acessing the Webservice which is another domain. This user does not have permissions to do access it. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I get the below error in the external list (The caller was not authenticated by the service)

Comment: OK, I did not understand your question, I think. You are simply asking how to surface a WCF service via BCS, correct? In this case, BCS is acting as a client. There is no cross-domain issue. I will delete this answer and get more clarification.

Comment: Yes, Actually i know how to surface the WCF service via BCS. But not sure if the web service is hosted on another domain. I am  getting the  above error when i access the external list

Comment: That does not matter. The BCS runtime is acting as a client directly to the service. Cross-Domain is not an issue here. The problem is with how the BCS runtime is authenticating to your WCF service.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I was able to solve this issue by changing wshttpbinindg to basicHttpbinidng( <endpoint address="http://18.15.158.125:186/CustomDataList.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SPListData.ICustomDataList">

Comment: That's interesting. I suppose that means it's using basci auth instead of NTLM. Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Apparently that means you have turned of authentication for that endpoint. Which explains why it works.

Comment: Sure Rob . I will Mark that as answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by making the below change in my web.config

wshttpbinindg to basicHttpbinidng( `<endpoint address="18.15.158.125:186/CustomDataList.svc"; binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SPListData.ICustomDataList">`

Also one more change which i made was for my web service in IIS instead of Apppool account i have given windows user account.